# A IFolderLayout have many viewpart how to show Full name of viewpart

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

There are a lot of viewPart in IFolderLayout,so the name of viewPart can only see the a character.
How to show full name of viewPart, even though there are a lot of verwPart.

Comment: Hover your mouse over view tab, you will see its full name. Also View icon is itself enough to identify the view type(Like in case Fast view)

Comment: now I am in coding not use it. And when i use setTitleToolTip(),Hover mouse over view tab will show TitleToolTip.are there have other ways? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a preference for the minimum widths of view tabs:

```
IWorkbenchPreferenceConstants.VIEW_MINIMUM_CHARACTERS
```

You can set the value in a preference initializer or in a plugin_customization.ini file like this:

```
org.eclipse.ui/VIEW_MINIMUM_CHARACTERS = -1
```

(-1 disables any shortening of the tabs)